# SQL join looking for newest record

Tags: sql

I have two tables with relevant fields as follows:-

USERS
UserID

LOGINS
UserID
Date

What I want to do is list all UserIDs from USERS with the last date they logged on from the LOGINS table.

I'm struggling to work out how to construct my SQL.

Comment: Can you share some of the SQL you have written so far? Which DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    users.userid,
    max(date)
from 
    users
        inner join logins on user.userid = logins.userid
group by users.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

Join on the table with an aggragate function on each user login group to select the `MAX` login `date`

I.e

```
SELECT users.id, MAX(logins.date) AS last_login FROM Users
JOIN logins ON user.Id = logins.user_id
GROUP BY users.Id
```

Heres an example in practice:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2adba3/8